# Shifting AC signal

Tags: ac, signal

I have an AC signal that is in the range of 1.5 V - 6.5 V and it needs to pass through a buffer with a single supply of 6 V to ground. So in this case, it needs to be shifted down by about 0.5 V so that it'll pass through the buffer without any headroom issues. What could be implemented assuming the only restriction is a single power supply of 6 V to ground and the signal must remain as precise as possible?
It also needs to be shifted back up at the output of the buffer.

Comment: Is the 6 volt restriction system-wide, and is the signal DC coupled?

Comment: @EM Fields Hi, the 6 volt restriction is system-wide and is DC coupled.

Answer (score 1):

Use an AC coupling capacitor with a value large enough to not effect the frequencies of interest. You can then set the zero point using biasing resistors.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUKQ6Z.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Choose \$\text{R1}\$ and \$\text{R2}\$ such that
$$
\text{R1}=\text{R2} \\ \text{R1} \parallel \text{R2} \ll Z_{in}
$$

and choose \$\text{C1}\$ such that 
$$
\frac{1}{2 \pi \left(\text{R1} \parallel \text{R2} \right) \text{C1}} \ll f_{input}
$$

Answer (score 0):

You may need to do nothing apart from coupling into the buffer using a suitable capacitor. It is very likely that the buffer will adjust the resting DC level to half of its swing (i.e. 3v). Similarly on the output end, the next stage in the chain is likely to do something very similar.

Obviously you will lose the exact DC reference, but your question does specify AC.

Comment: It is (or isn't) likely, it depends on the circuit. If OP asks how to shift a voltage I'd say he needs DC coupling.